# Maven reactor: Is it possible to build only the dependencies of a specific module, but not the module itself?

Tags: java, maven, maven-reactor

I would like to `install` all the dependencies of a given module (without the module itself), followed by a `deploy` of just the module.

```
mvn --file aggregator.xml clean install --also-make --projects :my-module-id
mvn --file aggregator.xml clean deploy --projects :my-module-id
```

Note 1: I cannot call just the `deploy:deploy`-goal on the module, because sometimes other goals are bound to the `deploy`-phase.

Note 2: I also need to avoid packaging `:my-module-id` twice, because it takes a long time.

[Maven command line options help](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-embedder/cli.html)

Example aggregator.xml (reactor pom):

```
<project>
  <name>aggregator</name>
  
  <modules>
    <module>common-module-id</module>
    <module>my-module-id</module>
  </module>
</project>
```

Comment: What is meant by: `without the module itself`? What is `aggregator.xml` ? Can you show that? The usual way in Maven 3 is to do a full `mvn install` and afterwards you can use `mvn -pl XX package` ... 
The question is why running first `clean install` and afterwars `clean deploy`? It might be a good idea to test Maven 4.0.0-alpha-7 it has a number of improvements in particular related to reactor handling...

Comment: BTW: Why other things bound to deploy phase??

Comment: @khmarbaise I added an example aggregator pom. Full install followed by -pl X package/deploy builds X twice (which I need to avoid, too expensive).

Comment: @khmarbaise Why other things bound to deploy phase? E.g. Maven assemply plugin copying artifacts somewhere, custom plugins uploading to custom update servers etc.

Comment: If you have maven-assembly-plugin bound to deploy phase sounds wrong... better put it either to prepare-package or package phase but not to deploy... Uploading to "custom servers" sounds like the wrong way because Maven is not a deploy tool... it's a build tool...

Comment: This part: `I added an example aggregator pom. Full install followed by -pl X package/deploy builds X twice (which I need to avoid, too expensive).` I don't understand? Why running first `install` and then `deploy`? Why not simply run `deploy`... etc. A full working example of your setup would be helpful otherwise it's not clear what you exactly doing and what the real problems are...

Comment: Sorry, maven-ant-run to copy stuff somewhere (not maven-assembly-plugin).

Comment: I want to build the dependencies only locally on the build machine (up to install phase), and deploy only the final module. The final module has a custom deploy plugin. If the package phase of the final module wasn't so expensive, I would just first do `mvn install -pl my-module-id -am` followed by `mvn deploy -pl my-module-id` (thereby effectively packaging and installing the final module 2x)

Answer (score 1):

In case you never want to actually `deploy` those other modules (just `install` them to use them in the build), it would make more sense to set

`<maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>`

in the modules that should not be deployed. Then you can safely call

`mvn deploy --also-make --projects :my-module-id`

without deploying stuff you do not need later.

Comment: Some of the dependencies are snapshot versions that are deployed as part of another continuous integration jenkins job. But other dependencies are non-snapshot versions that are released manually, and should definitely not be deployed as part of this build.

Comment: And there might be other stuff bound to the deploy phase that does not honor the deploy skip flag.

Comment: Actually, I am skeptical about deploying modules "sometimes". Generally, the norm is just to deploy all the modules. They don't do harm, they might take a little disk space, but if you tidy up the SNAPSHOTs with a scheduled job, this is usually ok. I understand, that sometimes people say that module X should not be deployed, because it will not  be used and is really large. But then, I would stick to this all the time, and deploy it from one kind of build and not from the other.

Comment: We use this approach to build our deliverables. "my-module-id" is a "leaf-project" with no further downstream dependencies. It is an administrative decision by the project manager to build it after some issues have been resolved. It includes signed installers and other update-packages.

Comment: @RetoHöhener I probably did not make myself clear. I am talking about the dependencies of `my-module-id`. For each of these modules, it should be clear whether the module should be deployed or not. If it should not be deployed, skip the deploy plugin (and possibly other plugins that would be run during the deploy phase). What I did not like was the idea that some of these modules may be deployed "as part of another continuous integration jenkins job". For each module it should either be deployed always or never.

Comment: Agreed. More context: For every calendar year we have 50 'leaf-projects' and 100+ 'dependency-projects'. Each leaf-project depends on a subset of the dependencies. Most 'dependency-projects' are snapshots and could (should) always be deployed. But some 'dependency-projects' are manually versioned and deployed. I'm trying to figure out a common build pipeline script for the release process without having to manage hundreds of reactor poms or profiles.

Comment: What I did just now is I think similar to what you suggested: I created a flag `mvn -Dskip-final-module` to skip the expensive packaging in our custom plugin in the leaf-project. I'm almost happy with this except for the added complexity and the fact the the non-snapshot dependencies are also locally built and installed (which they shouldn't).